# Running Puppeteer with Headless chromium with AutoSelectCertificateForUrls

Tags: chromium

I am trying to set **AutoSelectCertificateForUrls** policy to my headless chromium that puppeteer uses.

This is the code I need to use:

```
{
  "AutoSelectCertificateForUrls": ["{\"pattern\":\"*\",\"filter\":{}}"]
}
```

However I have no clue where to put this code so my headless chromium will pick up the file and run with selected policy.

I will continue searching but if anyone has the solution it would be very appreciated.

This is puppeteer:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

I am using **Linux Mint**

To check if policy is set use following command:

```
chrome://policy/
```